# Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 - HTML Spaces being added "&nbsp;"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

After we did the upgrade of Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 a number of Article Pages now have the HTML equivalent of a space actually showing up in the text. ( ) Has anyone ever heard of this & is there a way to remove the `&nbsp;` from the pages and replace with an actual space?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure You have this Line in your pageLayOuts or master Pages

**`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`**

If no then try to add it in Master Pages in Head tag and then check again..

Let me know the Outcome

Thanks